# Masonry Resizing issue

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-masonry

we are working on a site which is responsive down to mobile. However the masonry is a bit glitchy in the sense that when the window is resized it moves to allow for another column, but the columns do not fill it

http://tbd.aaronnicholls.co.uk/work

Does anyone know a good fix for this

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you out. This is what I'm using on my site and the resizing works as it should. Perhaps if you modify your code, it will work for you as well.

The function below seems to be missing from your code. The #container is the container that wraps all the items. In your case it's the works-loop ul. The .span1BoxWrapper, is the items main wrapper. The problem seems to be with your main works-loop wrapper and its width. I took the width out in firebug and the items repositioned themselves properly. The missing function below should fix that.

Note: if I change my .js file to jquery.masonry.js (like you have), the layout does not work anymore so that might be the cause of your problem as well. Another cause might be that the boxes shrink as you resize the screen.

```
<!--boxes arrangement-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-transitions.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function(){

    $('#container').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.span1BoxWrapper',
      //cornerStampSelector: '.corner-stamp',
      columnWidth: 1,
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
      //isRTL: true,
      isFitWidth: true
    });

  });
</script>
<style>
#container{
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px 10px 0 0;
    border:1px dotted #ccc;
    margin:0 auto 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```